# how to find the number of specific enum members in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

I have an object that can come in various sizes.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public enum Size
{
    Small = 0,
    Medium,
    Large
}

public class BallSizes : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Size size;
}
```

After assigning the `Size` to various objects. I want to see how many objects are `Small` or `Large` etc.

`Enum.GetName()` and `Enum.GetValue()` seems to only return the names/values of the objects, instead of the total amount of objects that are of that type.

Comment: Your title and body ask different questions. Do you want to count the number of objects of each size, or find the number of members in an enum?

Comment: Where are those objects? Are they all in the same collection or where do you want to search them?

Comment: @JonasH You're right I meant count the number of a specific size. Changed the title.

Comment: `someenumerable.GroupBy(x=>x.Size).Select(x=>new { x.Key, x.Count() })`?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what "member in an enum" means. For the enum you are showing us that number is 3. But I'm quite sure that's not what you are after.

Comment: Well, you added a line of code in your last edit.  Show an entire class (the code you added will not compile as it is) and then describe what you want to do.  If you have a class `MyClass` that contains a private filed of type `Size`, and you have a collection of them somewhere, do you want to count the number of `MyClass` instances in that collection that are `Small`, `Medium` or `Large`?  or, do you want to do something else

Comment: @TimSchmelter The sizes are defined in a 'BallSizes' script separately from the objects

Comment: @Flydog57 yep the first question is what I am trying to figure out. I edited the code snippet so that it shows the entire class

Comment: Assuming you have all of your `BallSizes` objects in a collection named `myObjects`, have you tried @JonasH's answer, that looks about right?

Answer (score 3):

if you have a bunch of objects with different sizes, and want to count the number of each size, you could for example use LINQ

```
var counts = myObjects.GroupBy(obj => obj.Size).Select(group => (group.Key, group.Count());
```

---

Then for getting all your ball instances you could e.g. use [`FinsObjectsOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html)

```
var myObjects = FindObjectsOfType<BallSizes>();
```

are better already store them in a list right when you instantiate them